# MYSQL detecting overlap date range in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following data.

```
CREATE TABLE DiscountFormula (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, dateFrom date
, dateUntil date
);

INSERT INTO DiscountFormula
  (dateFrom, dateUntil)
VALUES
  ("2020-06-01", "2020-06-10")
, ("2020-06-03", "2020-06-13")
, ("2020-06-25", "2020-06-29")
, ("2020-07-01", "2020-07-01")
, ("2020-07-03", "2020-07-03")
;
```

[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34e3d3)

```
id    dateFrom     dateUtil     
====  ========     ========     
1     2020-06-01   2020-06-10  
2     2020-06-03   2020-06-13  
3     2020-06-25   2020-06-29
4     2020-07-01   2020-07-01
5     2020-07-03   2020-07-03
```

As you can see id `1` and `2` is overlap on a date range. I want to create a query to detect if any overlap date range in the table. Meaning if `count > 0` have overlap data so i can throw an alert message.
What I have try, but seem is not working.

```
SELECT * #count(*) as TOTAL
FROM DiscountFormula A
JOIN DiscountFormula B 
ON (A.dateFrom >= B.dateFrom AND A.dateFrom <= B.dateUntil)
OR (A.dateUntil >= B.dateFrom AND A.dateUntil <= B.dateUntil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula for detecting overlapping ranges is slightly off.  It should be this:

```
WHERE A.dateFrom < B.dateUntil
  AND A.dateUntil > B.dateFrom
  AND A.id <> B.id
```

Updated query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM DiscountFormula A
INNER JOIN DiscountFormula B
    ON A.dateFrom < B.dateUntil AND A.dateUntil > B.dateFrom AND
       A.id <> B.id;
```

Comment: but why if I add `WHERE A.id IN (2,3,4,5)` it still count > 0. this id's is not contain overlap date range?

Comment: @Nixoderm Good catch...you should also assert that `A.id <> B.id`, to avoid counting a single row as overlapping with itself during the self join.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a cumulative maximum:

```
select count(*)
from (select df.*,
             max(df.dateuntil) over (order by df.datefrom
                                     rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                    ) as prev_dateuntil
      from DiscountFormula df
     ) df
where prev_dateuntil > datefrom;
```

This should be much faster than a self-join.  If `count(*)` is `0` then there are no overlaps.

Actually, I think a `lag()` is sufficient for this problem:

```
select count(*)
from (select df.*,
             lag(df.dateuntil) over (order by df.datefrom) as prev_dateuntil
      from DiscountFormula df
     ) df
where prev_dateuntil > datefrom;
```